# HasOne Or References?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I've inherited a database and I'm trying to map it to Fluent NHibernate.
I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [Signatures](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED NOT NULL,
    -- Other Fields....
)

CREATE TABLE [SignoffSteps](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED NOT NULL,
    [SignatureId] [int] NULL REFERENCES [Signatures]([Id]),
    -- Other Fields....
)
```

And I'm attempting to map it to the following
(Extra properties and mappings omitted):

```
public class SignoffStep
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Signature Signature { get; set;}

    public class Map : ClassMap<SignoffStep>
    {
        public Map()
        {
            Table("SignoffSteps");
            Id(x => x.Id);

            References(x => x.Signature, "SignatureId")
                .Nullable()
                .ForeignKey("FK_SingoffSteps_Signatures")
                .Cascade.All()
                .Not.LazyLoad();
        }
    }
}

public class Signature
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public class Map : ClassMap<Signature>
    {
        public Map()
        {
            Table("Signatures");
            Id(x => x.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

This works great, except for one annoyance: deleting Signatures.  I can make it work if I manually delete the signature:

```
session.Delete(signoffStep.Signature);
signoffStep.Signature = null;
```

But what I'd like to do is just set the Signature property on the signoff step to null, and have NHibernate automatically delete the child.  Is there a way to setup my mapping to do this?

EDIT:  Setting Cascade to  "all-delete-orphan" not doable:
[image: Intellisense]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having a "ToDelete" property on the Signature, and manually deleting them while I'm saving. I don't like this b/c it break the abstraction but it works for now.

I think to really fix it I wanted to, I would have had to redo the tables and associations a bit.  Unfortunately this was out of the question in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Cascade setting to "all-delete-orphan". Currently you're cascading everything EXCEPT deletes, meaning that the DB will complain when you try to create an "orphan" record. By telling NHibernate how to deal with this (delete any orphaned records in the referenced table after an update or delete operation), you avoid the problem.

Understand that in order for NH's cascading to work, the FK of the referencing table must be nullable, so that NH can set it to null (orphaning the record) in its first pass. AFAIK, NH does not currently provide for a way to cascade deletion of child records with a non-nullable FK.

Comment: Added edit above. Cascade all-delete-orphan isn't possible with a References relation, I think that is only on HasMany.